# Where to find cherry blossom dates for Stockholm

Tags: events, seasonal, stockholm

It's the beginning of April, and the cherry trees will soon bloom in Stickholm, one of the most famous locations for this event being the King's Garden (Körsbärsblom i Kungsträdgården).

I live abroad (France), and I would like to find forecasts, or at least some online resource which will indicate when the bloom has started (so that I could book a trip a few days later).

I understand a little bit of Swedish, so I can clumsily navigate Swedish websites, but I couldn't find such resources. The [japanexperterna.se](http://www.japanexperterna.se/artiklar/korsbarsprognos) website contains cherry tree bloom forecasts, but only seems to cover cities in Japan.

I also tried looking for online "live cams", but couldn't find one with cherry trees in the field of view.

**Is there a website that I could regularly check which would give approximate forecasts, or at least indicate when the cherry tree bloom in Stockholm started?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no forecast per se that I can find, although the cherry blossom day event will be on the [22nd of April](http://www.stockholm.se/KulturFritid/Konst-och-museer/kungstradgarden/Kungstradgardens-kalender/) this year at Kungsträdgården. Then some kind of celebration/event is done in conjunction with the Japanese community, so the bloom should have started by then.

Every spring the cherry bloom seems to result in some activity on news sites and social media. It seems to me that the best bet of following the trees is to follow social media - [the #kungsträdgården tag on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/kungstr%C3%A4dg%C3%A5rden/) should be quite helpful. As of this moment, three photos of the cherry blossom trees have been posted within the last hour.

Comment: And other method might be trying to see cherry blossom photos from other countries, following the event north to Sweden? Most of the trees are fully in bloom in the Netherlands, have been only a few days so far.

Comment: @Willeke Whereas the ones in Japan started blooming at the end of March and will continue into May travelling up the country South to North in 1 - 2 week bursts. This doesn't seem like much of a reliable indicator. If it was they wouldn't bloom in Sweden until June.

Answer (score 2):

The [official page](http://www.stockholm.se/kungstradgarden) does not contain much information about dates. But on the [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/kungstradgarden) maintained by officials working with the park they post information continuously (in swedish).

(Cherry trees are actually a recent feature added to Kungsträdgården. The more traditional tree is the elm that was the cause of [the elm conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm_Conflict) back in 1971.)